# Kubernetes config separation between environments and services

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Let us say you have a system with 3 deployment environents (e.g. dev, uat, prod) and 10 services that need to share configuration that varies per environment, like database host URL etc.

Ideally, should define the environment config (databases and other infrastructure) once per environment, not 10 times on every service configmap.

- How to best maintain this separation of configuration of environments and applications?
- How to best inject the environment config on every application deployed on that environment?

Comment: This may help you. https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/7f9sh2/helm_production_x_staging_charts/

Comment: I'm guessing your posting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52854446/kubernetes-config-on-code-repo-vs-on-helm-charts-repo means you're following the advice of @VKR and looking at helm for this?